# How to change coordinate system from one plane to another?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, plane-geometry, affine-geometry, computer-vision

I have two planes plane1 and plane2 which equations are known. Given a point c with coordinates (x,y,z) of the plane plane1, is there any way to get the correspondent point c' on plane2?
I've tried with the affine transformations but I don't know the matrix transformation.

Comment: how is c' gotten from c?

Comment: Why does point $c$ have coordinate $(x,y,z)$ if it is in a *plane*?

Comment: The goal is to find c' given c and the plane equations.

Comment: The c coordinate is a 3D point because I am working in a 3D environment

Comment: @vipulkumar If you know how the basis vectors are transformed, and if the transformation is linear, you can write the linear transformation as a matrix, whose $i$th column is the transformation applied to the $i$th basis vector

Comment: @Golden_Ratio Unfortunately, I don't know how the basis vectors change. Is there any way to compute it?

Comment: @vipulkumar But it's unclear how you are mapping points from one plane to another. There are infinitely many ways to do so. And do you even have a linear space? (e.g. do your planes contain the origin?)

Comment: @Golden_Ratio Yes the planes contain the origin